# Artin's Algebra Exercise: Characterize all rings $R$ which contains $\mathbb C$ and has dimension $2$ as a vector space over $\mathbb C$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, vector-spaces

Here is a problem from Artin's Algebra text:

> Characterize all rings $R$ which contains $\mathbb C$ and has dimension $2$ as a vector space over $\mathbb C$.

**Here is my idea**: Suppose $\{1, \alpha\}$ is a basis of $R$ as a $\mathbb C$-vectorspace, then as $\alpha^2 \in R$ so there exist $a,b \in \mathbb C$ such that $\alpha^2=a\alpha + b$. Now the whole multiplication is defined, since $(s\alpha + t)(u\alpha+v) = su\alpha^2 + (sv+tu)\alpha + tv = (sua + sv + tu)\alpha + (sub + tv)$, for generic elements $s\alpha + t, u\alpha+v \in R$. Such a ring is clearly commutative. Is this solution correct ? Moreover,

> What can be said more about ring $R$ ?
>   How can we find all rings which contains $\mathbb C$ has dimensions $n$ as a vector space Over $\mathbb C$ ? Any ideas?

Comment: Different values of $a$ and $b$ will sometimes give rise to the same (i.e. isomorphic) rings.  For example, if you take $1, \alpha$ as your basis, and $\alpha^2=0$, then I could take $1, \alpha'= \alpha+1$ as my basis and have $(\alpha')^2=2\alpha'-1$.

Comment: This is an ok beginning. Hint: Consider the polynomial $p(x)=x^2-ax-b$. This is the characteristic polynomial of multiplication by $\alpha$ viewed as a linear mapping from $R$ to itself. Because $\Bbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, the polynomial $p(x)$ splits into a product of linear factors. What more can you say about $R$, when those two factors are the same, i.e. $p$ has a double root? What can you say, when those are distinct? In the latter case *the Chinese Remainder Theorem is your friend.*

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks! Following your hint,I've posted a solution.Please have a look.Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following Jyrki Lahtonen hint, here is my solution:

Let's work with an arbitrary field. Let $k$ be any field. If $R$ is a $2$-dimensional $k$-algebra, it must have a basis $\{ 1, x \}$ where $x$ is not a scalar multiple of $1$; in particular, it must be commutative, since it is generated by $x$. Since it is $2$-dimensional, $x^2 = ax + b$ for some $a, b \in k$, and it follows that $R \cong k[x]/(x^2 - ax - b)$. The isomorphism type of $R$ is now controlled by the possible types of monic quadratic polynomials over $k$. There are three cases:

1. $x^2 - ax - b$ has two distinct roots in $k$. In this case $R \cong k \times k$ by the Chinese remainder theorem.
2. $x^2 - ax - b$ is irreducible over $k$. In this case $R$ is a quadratic field extension of $k$.
3. $x^2 - ax - b$ has two repeated roots in $k$. In this case $R \cong k[x]/x^2$.

If $k$ is algebraically closed then the second case never occurs and we conclude that there are exactly two isomorphism types of $2$-dimensional $k$-algebras.